# Getting Excalibur as a neutral human

Tags: nethack

So typically I'll go as a Lawful Human Valkyrie in order to be able to dip for Excalibur, and have the gnomes be angry at me so that I can get their sweet, sweet XP.

But today, half-awake, I created a neutral valk by accident.  Is there anyway to get Excalibur, short of wishing for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only sources of Excalibur in standard Nethack are as follows:

- Arti-wishing for it (not guaranteed if 2+ artifacts exist in-game)
- Dipping as a lawful character
- Being Crowned as a lawful character while wielding a non-artifact Longsword
- Finding it from the bones file of a character with it

Ignoring the final option because it's RNG and gamey, the short answer is **no**. It's also worth nothing that even if you *do* arti-wish up an Excalibur, it is an intelligent artifact and will blast your unworthy, Totally Not Lawful behind when you wish for it and when you wield it. (4d10 damage, or 2d10 with Magic Resistance. You do have Magic Resistance, right?)

Comment: Heh, well in regards to your question this character died of YASD a while back, but good info to know nonetheless.

Comment: @espais Look at it not as YASD, but yet another thing to learn for future ascensions-to-be! :P

Comment: oh indeed....always learn something new in this game!